# Speeding up canvas image drawing

Tags: javascript, image, svg, html5-canvas, benchmarking

I'm trying to draw a lot of images in a canvas (like 2000). I want to repeat this operation at least 8-10 times (on different canvases). I have trying to benchmark my code:

```js
const CANVAS_SIZE = 281;

const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

const generateCoordinates = (n) => {
  const coordinates = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const x = getRandom(0, CANVAS_SIZE);
    const y = getRandom(0, CANVAS_SIZE);
    coordinates.push([x, y]);
  }
  return coordinates;
};

const benchmark = (n, draw) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = "svg.svg";
  const coordinates = generateCoordinates(n);
  const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  const t0 = performance.now();

  for (let i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
    const [x, y] = coordinates[i];
    context.drawImage(img, x, y);
  }

  const t1 = performance.now();
  return (t1 - t0) / 1000;
};
```

But the problem is that even though it returns very few milliseconds, the final image takes a while to load. I do not know why this is happening. I have been reading and it may be the image loading time, but that does not make sense because I'm running that code in local with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Canvas</title>
</head>

<script src="index.js"></script>

<style>
    .canvas {
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .canvas-wrapper {
        border: 1px solid green;
        display: flex;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="canvas-wrapper">
        <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas" width="281" height="281"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And the attached svg file. Does anyone know how to speed it up? I have also tried using [an offscreen canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas) but I have not been able to make it work.

Comment: If you draw 2000 images 8-10 times in a row, that will inevitably take some time.

Comment: Here's your code: https://jsfiddle.net/rqoc2bma/ I'm not getting a delay. As soon as the image is loaded, the background turns red. After drawing the image 2000 times, which takes 0.4 seconds for me, the background turns green. You don't see the red.

Comment: What hardware / software are you testing on?  In @ChrisG's link, it logs times like 0.057... (seconds) in Chromium on an i7-6700k (Skylake) CPU.  Maybe Chris was running a much slower CPU, and/or higher resolution screen, or a CPU without hardware P-state control so it doesn't ramp up from idle to to max turbo frequency nearly as fast. (Skylake HW P-state management is notably good for web client benchmarks, giving great burst performance vs. only having the OS consider ramping up every maybe 10 ms or slower).

Comment: @PeterCordes Heh, I tested it in Firefox. In Chrome I'm getting 0.06 seconds :)

Comment: I don't know the exact problem here, but I think you should make sure that the image is loaded before drawing it on canvas. So, before `img.src = "svg.svg"` assign a callback function to the load event: `img.addEventListener('load', e => { ... context.drawImage(e.target, x, y); ...});`